# Finding maximum value of one column (by group) and inserting value into another data frame in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

All,

I was hoping someone could find a solution to an issue of mine that isn't necessarily causing headaches, but, as of right now, invites the possibility for human error in creating a data set for a project on which I'm working.

The data set I'm using right now is a directed dyad-year (A vs. B, B vs. A) data set for select pairs of countries for every year between 1950 and 2010. Some countries, like A in my example, will be paired with every country in the world and every country will be paired with it. Some countries, like B and C in my example, will be paired with just a few countries. Some pairs will have missing data, which I don't show in my example.

What I would like to do is use R to find the maximum value of a given column, for a given country, in a given year, and insert that value into another data frame. Hopefully this illustration will clarify what I would like to do.

```
country1 country2 year    x1   x2   x3   x4
   A        B     2000    50   30   1    20
   A        C     2000    70    2   5    90
   A        D     2000    10   90   20   30
   A        E     2000    95   10   10   5
   A        F     2000    10   10   10   0
   A        G     2000    5     5   0    0
   A        H     2000    10   30   25   40

  ........................................

  B        A      1998    5    10   30   2
  B        D      1998    30   6    9    0
  B        I      1998    10   9    7    0

  ........................................

  C        A      2005    10   15   2    6
  C        D      2005    90   0    0    40
  C        X      2005    49   90   5    0
```

Say, for example, that I'm interested in Country A in the year 2000. I want to know what is its max value of `x1` in 2000 (which is 95, in its pairing with Country E). I also want to know what is its max value for `x2`, `x3`, and `x4` in any pairing in that given year (which are 90, 25, and 90 with Country D, Country H, and Country C respectively).

The same follows for Country B in 1998, and Country C in 2005.

After isolating the max value of those columns for a given country in a given year, I'd like to dump those values into a dataframe, like this.

```
country   year    x1max    x2max    x3max    x4max
  A       2000      95       90       25       90
  B       1998      30       10       30        2
  C       2005      90       90        5       40
```

I'm flexible on this part. It might just be easiest to dump those max values for each country into their own data frames of dimensions 1x5, and then use `rbind` to stack them together.

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed? It'd save me the hassle of having to do it manually, which, more than anything, invites the possibility of human error.

Reproducible code follows, though, since my question does hinge on isolating a particular year for a particular country (e.g. 2000 for Country A instead of 2001), I'm not sure the reproducible code is necessarily helpful. I hope it is, or, at least, that my question is clear.

```
country1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
country2 <- c("B","C","D","E","F","G","H","A","D","I","A","D","X")
year <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 1998, 1998, 1998, 2005, 2005, 2005)
x1 <- c(50, 70, 10, 95, 10, 5, 10, 5, 30, 10, 10, 90, 49)
x2 <- c(30, 2, 90, 10, 10, 5, 30, 10, 6, 9, 15, 0, 90)
x3 <- c(1, 5, 20, 10, 10, 0, 25, 30, 9, 7, 2, 0, 5)
x4 <- c(20, 90, 30, 5, 0,0,40,2,0,0,6,40,0)

Data=data.frame(country1=country1,country2=country2,year=year,x1=x1,x2=x2,x3=x3,x4=x4)
Data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4) ~ country1 + year, Data, max)
  country1 year x1 x2 x3 x4
1        B 1998 30 10 30  2
2        A 2000 95 90 25 90
3        C 2005 90 90  5 40
```

It's not very clear from your question how you want to proceed from there though....

Comment: It wasn't quite what I was looking for, but it certainly made the job a whole heck of a lot easier. I think, from there, I could just as easily isolate values for a given country in a given year. Thank you very much for suggesting that route.

Comment: @sm8402, if you can clarify your question, I'm happy to take another stab at it!

Comment: To be honest, I think you answered my question better than I asked it. What I originally wanted to get was maybe a 1x5 output for a given country in a given year. The `aggregate` function you gave me just gave me max values for all countries for all years, but, when exported to CSV, I'm much better able to copy-paste rows of interest into another data set on which I'm working. Your solution turned out a little more convenient than for what I originally asked. :-)

Comment: Nice work Am... I mean Ananda - I didn't realise you could `cbind` on the LHS of an `aggregate`. You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `ddply` from plyr package. Assuming your sample is data.

```
data<-structure(list(country1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    country2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 
    9L, 1L, 4L, 10L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
    "G", "H", "I", "X"), class = "factor"), year = c(2000L, 2000L, 
    2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 2005L, 
    2005L, 2005L), x1 = c(50L, 70L, 10L, 95L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 
    30L, 10L, 10L, 90L, 49L), x2 = c(30L, 2L, 90L, 10L, 10L, 
    5L, 30L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 15L, 0L, 90L), x3 = c(1L, 5L, 20L, 
    10L, 10L, 0L, 25L, 30L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 5L), x4 = c(20L, 
    90L, 30L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 40L, 0L)), .Names = c("country1", 
"country2", "year", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))

install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
ddply(data,.(country1,year),numcolwise(max))

  country1 year x1 x2 x3 x4
1        A 2000 95 90 25 90
2        B 1998 30 10 30  2
3        C 2005 90 90  5 40
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know SQL, then you could use `sqldf`function from this package:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html

```
df <- sqldf("select year, max(x1), max(x2), max(x3), max(x4) from Data group by year")
df
  year max(x1) max(x2) max(x3) max(x4)
1 1998      30      10      30       2
2 2000      95      90      25      90
3 2005      90      90       5      40
```