# How do you subset a data frame that has different values for the same two columns in R

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

dput(df)

```
structure(list(Metrics = c("db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", "db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", 
"db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", "db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", 
"db2.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", "db2.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", 
"db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", "db2.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", 
"db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", "db2.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", 
"db2.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", "db2.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", 
"db2.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", "db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", 
"db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", "db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", 
"db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", "db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", 
"db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)", "db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%)"
), Date = c(1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 
1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 
1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 
1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 
1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 1416257563.98707, 
1416257563.98707), Value = c(0, 0.02, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.07, 
0, 2.02, 0, 0, 9.32, 0.02, 9.27, 0, 12.72, 12.72, 12.72, 0.08, 
12.72), Type1 = c("type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", 
"type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", 
"type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", 
"type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", 
"type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", 
"type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", "type=rac_database", 
"type=rac_database", "type=rac_database")), .Names = c("Metrics", 
"Date", "Value", "Type1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(10092L, 
10097L, 10103L, 10104L, 10107L, 10108L, 10111L, 10112L, 10114L, 
10115L, 10116L, 10117L, 10118L, 10120L, 10121L, 10188L, 10189L, 
10190L, 10192L, 10216L))
```

this is a subset of a bigger data frame. As you can see for the same Metrics and Date, there are multiple different values. I would like to be able to only pick the max value for the same data and metrics type. So, for same date and metrics, I should have only one value which should be max point. Any ideas, How I could subset this df?

For example, for Metrics:  db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%) and Date: 1416257564

in my df, I should have one entry:

```
 db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%) 1416257564 12.72 type=rac_database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as given here [Finding maximum value of one column (by group) and inserting value into another data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539696/finding-maximum-value-of-one-column-by-group-and-inserting-value-into-another)

Assuming your data frame is called `df`

```
df_1 <- aggregate(Value ~ Metrics + Date + Type1, df, max)
df_1
#edit: removed 'cbind'
```

Output

```
                        Metrics       Date             Type1 Value
1 db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%) 1416257564 type=rac_database 12.72
2 db2.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%) 1416257564 type=rac_database  9.32
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
> # find the maximum for Value for each combination of Metrics and Date
> df2 <- aggregate(df$Value, by=list(Metrics=df$Metrics, Date=df$Date), max)
> colnames(df2)[3] <- "Value"

> # add the corresponding value for Type1
> df2$Type1 <- df[df$Metrics == df2$Metrics & df$Date == df2$Date & df$Value == df2$Value, "Type1"]

> # result
> df2
                        Metrics       Date Value             Type1
1 db1.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%) 1416257564 12.72 type=rac_database
2 db2.Tablespace_Space_Used_(%) 1416257564  9.32 type=rac_database
```